# php empty object member

Tags: php, object

I am within a class. I try to set an object member:

```
$this->list = "hello";
print $this->list;
```

It returns "hello";

However, `empty($this->list))` always return true.

But for non object member `$tmp = "hello"`, `empty($tmp)` return false.

Why `empty()` cannot be used on object member?

Update:
empty() is influenced by the the my code framework. That is why it does not work properly.

Comment: You need to provide some code, are you actually within a class or trying to create an object just through `$this->list = 'hello'`? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `$s = new stdClass;
$s->list = 'Hello';
var_dump($s); /*
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["list"]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
} */
var_dump(empty($s->list));
/* bool(false) */`

Comment: I used var_dump($this->list). It returns "string(5) hello". But empty($this->list) still return true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

  class Foo
  {
    var $bar;

    function Bar()
    {
      $this->bar = 'hello';
      echo "In class: " . (empty($this->bar) ? 'empty' : 'populated') . "\r\n";
    }
  }

  $foo = new Foo();
  $foo->Bar();

  echo "Out of class: " . (empty($foo->bar) ? 'empty' : 'populated');
```

Output:

> In class: populated
>   Out of class: populated

Not sure [what you mean](http://www.ideone.com/WUnBL). Maybe provide more code? Also, per the [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) manual, the following values are to be considered **empty**:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
  9 "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

Also, try using [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) on the object to confirm it's what you're expecting.

Comment: I used var_dump($this->list); empty($this->list); It returns string(5) hello true.

Comment: @chnet: That's interesting, it's got to have somethign else interfering. Just through a basic test (above) there is no issue with testing against object members.

Comment: @chnet: you ever discover the issue?